# update not getting at "updated" data

Tags: grails

I am doing an update on data in a page and when I debug

```
def VariantInstance = Variant.get(params.id)
```

and look at VariantInstance, data I have changed stays the same.  Shouldn't it be getting the new data?

Comment: Are you saving the updated instance before performing the get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not based on your code.  How do you think it would be getting the new data if all you're doing is getting the existing data from the database?

```
def VariantInstance = Variant.get(params.id)
VariantInstance.properties = params
```